# Bluemix cli panic

Tags: ubuntu, ibm-cloud

I'm currently trying the IBM Bluemix platform and I wanted to deploy my first app. Basically I just downloaded the starter code and wanted to deploy it with no changes.

What I did :

- Installed cf
- Installed bluemix cli

Unfortunately, the bluemix command (as well as the shortcut 'bx') does not work. I'm getting :

```
panic: invalid character '[' after object key:value pair    

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    panic(0x99b680, 0xc8202dfa60)
        /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.6.3.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n.initWithLocale(0xa80958, 0x5, 0xa80958)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n/i18n.go:61 +0x71
github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n.Init(0x7f1cd50675e8, 0xc820263db0, 0x7f1cd5067720, 0xe8c380, 0x20)
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n/i18n.go:55 +0x121
github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n.init()
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/i18n/i18n.go:41 +0x19a
github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin.init()
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/vendor/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/ibm-containers-cli/containers-plugin/wrapper_docker.go:79 +0x6e
main.init()
    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/Bluemix/bluemix-cli-release/main.go:14 +0x40
```

As far as I know I installed bluemix successfully (according to the install)

```
The Cloud Foundry CLI version 6.21 is already installed.
Copying files ...
The Bluemix Command Line Interface (Bluemix CLI) is installed successfully.
To get started, open a new Linux terminal and enter "bluemix help", or enter "bx help" as short name.    

With Bluemix CLI 0.4.0 or later, the CLI can automatically collect diagnostic and usage information and send it to Bluemix for analysis.
This information will help us better understand current client usage and plan for future use. No personally identifiable data is collected.    

To stop collecting information, you can run the following command:
        'bluemix config --usage-stats-collect false'
```

What have I done that went wrong ?

Thanks !

Matthieu

Comment: what is your operating system? did you install the correct cli for your operating system?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu and I have installed the appropriate cli (there is only one available [here](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exact solution to your problem, but you don't need the Bluemix CLI to push a cloud foundry app to Bluemix. You can just use the Cloud Foundry CLI.

The [docs](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/cfcommands/index.html) have some details on how to get started, but the basic commands you'll need are:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net/
```

If you are in a non US region replace `ng` with `eu-gb` or `au-syd`
Then follow the instructions to login.
Lastly, from the directory of the the starter code run

```
cf push [name of application]
```

You can also use the `-m` flag to set memory, i.e. `-m 256m` for 256mb and you can use the `-b` flag to set the buildpack. You can see a list of preloaded buildpacks with `cf buildpacks`, but you can also use custom buildpacks.

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! Actually I've found out that I can push directly using git, and even better linked a Github repository to the Bluemix' one and that is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for :)